# Index match - multiple criteria - one which is max

Tags: excel

Lets say I have three columns of data in Excel

```
IDno | Date | Indicator
```

There are duplicate entries in the IDno column.

I want to use a formula to return the indicator value based on a certain IDno with the highest date.

For example, how would I get the value "4" below

```
IDno | Date | Indicator
1      01/01 2
1      01/02 3
1      01/03 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$4)/(($B$2:$B$4=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$4/(A2:A4=1),1))*($A$2:$A$4=1)),1))
```

[image]

---

Or if your data in C is numeric **AND** there is only one entry per day per IDno then you can use this:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,1,B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$4/(A2:A4=1),1))
```

---

Also if the two rules from above and you have Office 365 Excel with MAXIFS():

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,1,B:B,MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following as an array formula (enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=INDEX(C2:C15,MATCH(1&MAX(IF(A2:A15=1,B2:B15)),A2:A15&B2:B15,0))
```

I have kept 1 as a constant, but you can change that to a cell reference.